# objected oriented and parsing csv

Tags: ruby

i have to parse csv file which has customers and product they have ordered . customers can repeat for different product . i have to get all the unique customers and products they have ordered. Then print out each customer and there product . i have been asked to do in a object oriented way so
1) should i create a customer objects and have a product as there attribute 
2) just write a program using foreach and loop through and store customer and product in  a hash and print it out .

what throws me off is i have been asked to do it in a object oriented way. if do it by creating objects how can i store a custom object in memory ? so that if i come across a customer second time i have to add the product and at the end i have to loop through all the objects  and print it out . sorry i have bad English thanks reading a long question and for the help.

Comment: Maybe you should post how you would do it and ask for suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you store a custom object in memory? By creating the object and keeping it in a list, hash, or whatever seems appropriate. (Probably a hash, with the key being whatever unique value you have in your CSV, and the value would be a collection of products.)

Being asked to do it in "an object-oriented way" is a little arbitrary, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FasterCSV or Ruby 1.9 you can extend the parser allowing you to map each CSV row to a custom object.

```
# http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-load
# http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-dump
# https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv/blob/master/test/tc_serialization.rb
require 'csv'

class Person
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :email

  def self.csv_load(meta, headers, row)
    person = Person.new
    headers.each.with_index { |h,i|
      person.send "#{h}=", row[i]
    }
    person
  end

  def self.parse(csv)
    meta = "class,#{self.to_s}\n"
    CSV.load("#{meta}#{csv}")
  end

  def dump
    self.class.dump([self])
  end

  def self.dump(people, io='', options={})
    CSV.dump(people, io, options).strip
  end

  def self.csv_meta
    []
  end

  def csv_headers
    %w(id name email)
  end

  def csv_dump(headers)
    headers.map { |h| self.instance_variable_get "@#{h}" }
  end

end

CSV_DUMP = <<-CSV
class,Person
id=,name=,email=
1,"First Dude",dude@company.com
2,"Second Dude",2nddude@company.com
3,"Third Dude",3rddude@company.com
CSV

CSV_INPUT = <<-CSV
id,name,email
1,"First Dude",dude@company.com
2,"Second Dude",2nddude@company.com
3,"Third Dude",3rddude@company.com
CSV

CSV_DUMP2 = <<-CSV
class,Person
#{CSV_INPUT}
CSV

people = Person.parse(CSV_INPUT)
puts people.inspect
dumped =  Person.dump(people)
puts dumped
puts "----"
puts Person.parse(dumped).inspect
```